# Decreasing specific elements in a matrix

Tags: matrix, function-construction

Let

```
a = {{2, 2}, {2, 2}};
```

Why does

```
(--(a[[#]])) & @@@ {{1, 2}, {2, 1}}
```

give

> `{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}`

I expected

> `{{2, 1}, {1, 2}}`

Let

```
p = {2, 1};
```

Is there any easier way to decrease matrix elements; for example, the second in the first row and the first in the second row?

That is, I would like a function

```
F[a, p]
```

which gives

> `{{2, 1}, {1, 2}}`

Is there an easier and faster way to do this than the below:

```
(--(a[[#]])) & @@@ Transpose[{Range[2], p]
```

Comment: Use `##`, not `#`... also, *avoid using uppercase initials* for your symbols, else you risk clashing with built-ins...

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to do it:

```
With[
 {
  a = {{2, 2}, {2, 2}},
  f = Subtract[#, 1] &,
  p = {{1, 2}, {2, 1}}
 },
 MapAt[f, a, p]
 ]
```

MapAt responds to your specific request of, "for example the second in the first row and the first in the second row? That is a function"

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you would like to modify a matrix in-place.

```
SetAttributes[decrease, HoldFirst];

decrease[m_?MatrixQ, pos__List] :=
 Do[m[[Sequence @@ p]]--, {p, {pos}}]
```

Example:

```
SeedRandom[1];
test = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {5, 3}]
```

> `{{5, 3, 5}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 1}, {1, 4, 3}, {1, 4, 5}}`

Let's decrease second row all together, first element in third row, second and third in fourth and last in last:

```
decrease[test, {2}, {3, 1}, {4, {2, 3}}, {-1, -1}];

test
```

> `{{5, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 3, 1}, {1, 3, 2}, {1, 4, 4}}`

---

**Edit:** Incorporating a feature of a general modifying function.

```
SetAttributes[modifier, HoldFirst];

modifier[m_?MatrixQ, pos__List, f_Function: (# - 1 &)] :=
 Do[Set[
   m[[Sequence @@ p]], f@m[[Sequence @@ p]]], {p, {pos}}]
```

Leave out the optional function and the specified elements will be decreased by one, or specify the modifying operation, for example:

```
modifier[test, {2}, {3, 1}, 10 # - 2 &]
```

Answer (score 1):

To see what is wrong with your code, you can use `Trace` which shows that the '--' decrement happens before the `[[ ]]` look up.  I couldn't find a simple way of adapting your code, but I would aim to use something simpler.

I like to work in terms of matrices, and `SparseArray` gives you an convenient way to construct the required matrix.  If you need to update your matrix `a` this is one way to do it.

```
a = {{2, 2}, {2, 2}};
p = {{1, 2}, {2, 1}};
a -= SparseArray[p -> 1]
```